# How to update default IOS icon on PhoneGap app?

Tags: android, ios, cordova

I'm developing an app. using PhoneGap 3.5.0.  I'm trying to customize the app. default icon for IOS.  I updated the 4 icon files in www/res/icon/ios with my custom icons, rebuilt and re-deployed but the app. still shows up with the default PhoneGap icon.

I was able to get my custom icons working with the Android version.

Can anyone think what could be wrong?

Answer (score 1):

you need to specify in config.xml file as well. Please refer http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.5.0/config_ref_images.md.html#Icons%20and%20Splash%20Screens for more details.